# tkinter Treeview's insert method is not working when accessed from outside of the class

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I am trying to insert new entry in tkinter `Treeview` but it's not working and not showing any errors.
The following is the small version of my code.

```
class First:
   ...
   ...
    for c in self.bill_tree.get_children():
        i = self.bill_tree.item(c)['values']
        Second().add_to_tree(i)
   ...
   ...
```

What I am trying to do is get children from class `First` and then insert them to `Second` class, but it's not working. I created a `add` method to test and it inserts data, but when I try to do it with `add_to_tree` it fails.

```
class Second:
     ....
     self.bill_tree1 = ttk.Treeview(self, show='tree')
     tree_scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.bill_tree1.yview)

     self.bill_tree1.config(yscrollcommand=tree_scroll_y.set, columns=('#0','#1','#2','#3''))
     self.bill_tree1.column("#0", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=0)
     self.bill_tree1.column("#1", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=40, anchor='center')
     self.bill_tree1.column("#2", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=180, anchor='w')
     self.bill_tree1.column("#3", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=90, anchor='center')

     tree_scroll_y.place(relx=0.578, rely=0.186,width=20, height=299)
     self.bill_tree1.place(relx=0.013,rely=0.185, width=780, height=301)

 def add(self):
     self.bill_tree1.insert('','end', values=('value 1','value 2','value 3'))

 def add_to_tree(self, i):
     self.bill_tree1.insert('','end', values=(i))
```

following is the mini example of my project where all classes are created called from home class and placed on top of each other to achieve multi page window.

```
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import tkinter as tk

class Home(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

        Second().add_to_tree(l)
        
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Second, First):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.configure(width=1344, height=750)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(First)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class First(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
        Second().add_to_tree(l)
        tk.Button(self, text='add', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Second)).pack()


class Second(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, controller=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.bill_tree1 = ttk.Treeview(self, show='tree')
        tree_scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.bill_tree1.yview)

        self.bill_tree1.config(yscrollcommand=tree_scroll_y.set, columns=('#0','#1','#2','#3'))
        self.bill_tree1.column("#0", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=0)
        self.bill_tree1.column("#1", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=40, anchor='center')
        self.bill_tree1.column("#2", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=180, anchor='w')
        self.bill_tree1.column("#3", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=90, anchor='center')

        tree_scroll_y.place(relx=0.578, rely=0.186,width=20, height=299)
        self.bill_tree1.place(relx=0.013,rely=0.185, width=780, height=301)

        # tk.Button(self, text='add 1', command=self.add).grid()


    def add(self):
        self.bill_tree1.insert('','end', values=('value 1','value 2','value 3'))

    def add_to_tree(self, i):
        self.bill_tree1.insert('','end', values=(i))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Home()
    app.geometry('1300x700')
    app.mainloop()
```

i need to send data to second class

Comment: The statement `Second().add_to_tree(i)` creates an instance of `Second` which creates a `Treeview` and then it adds something to it **each iteration of the loop** so there's a bunch of separate `Treeview` widgets being created that have nothing to do with one another. You need to create a single `Treeview` widget and insert multiple items into it — so maybe there should only be one instance of `Second` created outside the loop.

Comment: @martineau sir, i tried your suggession by changing code to ```l = []``` ```for c in self.bill_tree.get_children():```    ```l.append(self.bill_tree.item(c)['values'])``` ```Second().add_to_tree(l)```  and then inserting through loop in ```add_to_code``` but not working

Comment: Sorry I can't really read that. However it looks like you're still creating multiple instances of the `Second` class. It would be best if you edited your question and provided a runnable [mre] (MRE).

Comment: you have to create instance only once `s = Second()` and later send it to other classes as argument - `First(s)` and `def __init__(self, s): self.s = s` and `self.s.add_to_tree(i)`

Comment: Sir, kindly check my question i added mini version of my project

Comment: in `First()` you have to use `controller.frames[Second]` instead of `Second()`. I added it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't create minimal working code so I will use my example code.

---

You have to create `Second()` only once and send it to `First()` as argument and it should remember it in variable and use it.

```
# --- classes ---

class First():

 def __init__(self, second):
    
     self.second = second

     for c in self.bill_tree.get_children():
         i = self.bill_tree.item(c)['values']
         self.second.add_to_tree(i)

# --- main ---

s = Second()

f = First(s)
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# --- classes ---

class First(tk.Frame):

 def __init__(self, master, second, **kwargs):
     super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
     
     self.second = second
     
     self.bill_tree = ttk.Treeview(self, show='tree')
     
     tree_scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.bill_tree.yview)

     self.bill_tree.config(yscrollcommand=tree_scroll_y.set, columns=('#0','#1','#2','#3'))
     self.bill_tree.column("#0", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=0)
     self.bill_tree.column("#1", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=40, anchor='center')
     self.bill_tree.column("#2", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=180, anchor='w')
     self.bill_tree.column("#3", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=90, anchor='center')

     tree_scroll_y.place(relx=0.578, rely=0.186,width=20, height=299)
     self.bill_tree.place(relx=0.013,rely=0.185, width=780, height=301)

 def add(self):
     self.bill_tree.insert('','end', values=('value 1','value 2','value 3'))

 def add_to_tree(self, i):
     self.bill_tree.insert('','end', values=(i))

 def copy(self):
     for c in self.bill_tree.get_children():
         i = self.bill_tree.item(c)['values']
         self.second.add_to_tree(i)
   
class Second(tk.Frame):
    
 def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
     super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

     self.bill_tree1 = ttk.Treeview(self, show='tree')
     
     tree_scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.bill_tree1.yview)

     self.bill_tree1.config(yscrollcommand=tree_scroll_y.set, columns=('#0','#1','#2','#3'))
     self.bill_tree1.column("#0", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=0)
     self.bill_tree1.column("#1", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=40, anchor='center')
     self.bill_tree1.column("#2", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=180, anchor='w')
     self.bill_tree1.column("#3", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=90, anchor='center')

     tree_scroll_y.place(relx=0.578, rely=0.186,width=20, height=299)
     self.bill_tree1.place(relx=0.013,rely=0.185, width=780, height=301)

 def add(self):
     self.bill_tree1.insert('','end', values=('value 1','value 2','value 3'))

 def add_to_tree(self, i):
     self.bill_tree1.insert('','end', values=(i))
   
# --- main ---
                                                                    
root = tk.Tk()

s = Second(root, width=300, height=100)
s.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
s.add()

f = First(root, s, width=300, height=100)
f.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
f.add()
f.add()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Copy All', command=f.copy)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

If main window would be class object and `Second` and `First` would be elements in this class

```
self.s = Second(self)
self.f = First(self)
```

Then `First` would use `self.master` to access main window and use `self.master.s` to access `Second`

---

Minimal working code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# --- classes ---

class First(tk.Frame):

 def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
     super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
     
     self.bill_tree = ttk.Treeview(self, show='tree')
     
     tree_scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.bill_tree.yview)

     self.bill_tree.config(yscrollcommand=tree_scroll_y.set, columns=('#0','#1','#2','#3'))
     self.bill_tree.column("#0", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=0)
     self.bill_tree.column("#1", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=40, anchor='center')
     self.bill_tree.column("#2", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=180, anchor='w')
     self.bill_tree.column("#3", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=90, anchor='center')

     tree_scroll_y.place(relx=0.578, rely=0.186,width=20, height=299)
     self.bill_tree.place(relx=0.013,rely=0.185, width=780, height=301)

 def add(self):
     self.bill_tree.insert('','end', values=('value 1','value 2','value 3'))

 def add_to_tree(self, i):
     self.bill_tree.insert('','end', values=(i))

 def copy(self):
     for c in self.bill_tree.get_children():
         i = self.bill_tree.item(c)['values']
         self.master.s.add_to_tree(i)
   
class Second(tk.Frame):
    
 def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
     super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

     self.bill_tree1 = ttk.Treeview(self, show='tree')
     
     tree_scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.bill_tree1.yview)

     self.bill_tree1.config(yscrollcommand=tree_scroll_y.set, columns=('#0','#1','#2','#3'))
     self.bill_tree1.column("#0", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=0)
     self.bill_tree1.column("#1", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=40, anchor='center')
     self.bill_tree1.column("#2", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=180, anchor='w')
     self.bill_tree1.column("#3", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=90, anchor='center')

     tree_scroll_y.place(relx=0.578, rely=0.186,width=20, height=299)
     self.bill_tree1.place(relx=0.013,rely=0.185, width=780, height=301)

 def add(self):
     self.bill_tree1.insert('','end', values=('value 1','value 2','value 3'))

 def add_to_tree(self, i):
     self.bill_tree1.insert('','end', values=(i))
   
# --- main ---
                                                                    
root = tk.Tk()

root.s = Second(root, width=300, height=100)
root.s.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
root.s.add()

root.f = First(root, width=300, height=100)
root.f.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
root.f.add()
root.f.add()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Copy All', command=root.f.copy)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

In your new example you have to use

- in `Home`: `self.frames[Second]` instead of `Second()`
- in `First`: `controller.frames[Second]` instead of `Second()`

Minimal working code

```
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import tkinter as tk

class Home(tk.Tk):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
        #Second().add_to_tree(l)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Second, First):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.configure(width=1344, height=750)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(First)

        # has to be after loop which create `Second()`
        self.frames[Second].add_to_tree(l)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class First(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        # it is good to keep it as class variable to use it in other functions in class
        self.controller = controller
        
        l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
        
        #Second().add_to_tree(l)
        self.controller.frames[Second].add_to_tree(l)
        
        tk.Button(self, text='add', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Second)).pack()


class Second(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, controller=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # it is good to keep it as class variable to use it in other functions in class
        self.controller = controller
        
        self.bill_tree1 = ttk.Treeview(self, show='tree')
        tree_scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.bill_tree1.yview)

        self.bill_tree1.config(yscrollcommand=tree_scroll_y.set, columns=('#0','#1','#2','#3'))
        self.bill_tree1.column("#0", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=0)
        self.bill_tree1.column("#1", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=40, anchor='center')
        self.bill_tree1.column("#2", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=180, anchor='w')
        self.bill_tree1.column("#3", stretch='no', minwidth=0, width=90, anchor='center')

        tree_scroll_y.place(relx=0.578, rely=0.186,width=20, height=299)
        self.bill_tree1.place(relx=0.013,rely=0.185, width=780, height=301)

        # tk.Button(self, text='add 1', command=self.add).grid()


    def add(self):
        self.bill_tree1.insert('','end', values=('value 1','value 2','value 3'))

    def add_to_tree(self, i):
        self.bill_tree1.insert('','end', values=(i))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Home()
    app.geometry('1300x700')
    app.mainloop()
```